# Multiple subqueries to find answer

Tags: sql

I have to list all product names that a customer has bought. I CANNOT use joins, so I must use a subquery or a correlated subquery. It takes 4 tables to find the answer, I need to use the customer table, sales order table, item table,and product table. The customer-sales order tables are connected by customer_id, the sales order-item tables are connected by order id, and the item-product tables are connected by product id. I can make a subquery to find the first part, and a subquery to find the last part. But I can't seem to get all of them to connect together for some reason. It keeps telling me I'm missing a right parenthesis.... Here is what I have thus far. (Using Oracle 10g)

```
SELECT order_id
FROM a_sales_order s
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT 'X'
FROM a_customer c
WHERE s.customer_id=c.customer_id AND name='Thermo Power')
```

This will give me a list of all the order id's the company im looking for has made. I then need to make another subquery to get the item id's of all the items in the order id's provided:

```
SELECT item_id
FROM a_item i
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT 'X'
FROM a_sales_order s
WHERE s.order_id=i.order_id)
```

and then a final subquery that turns the item IDs into product names:

```
SELECT product_name
FROM a_product p
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT 'X'
FROM a_item i
WHERE i.product_id=p.product_id)
```

The problem is when I try to add these all together im getting errors, and im not sure how I am suppose to join them all together.

```
SELECT product_name
FROM a_product p
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT 'X'
FROM a_item I
WHERE i.Product_id=p.product_id)
AND EXISTS
SELECT item_id
FROM a_item I
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT 'X'
FROM a_sales_order s
WHERE s.order_id=i.order_id)
AND EXISTS
SELECT order_id
FROM a_sales_order s
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT 'X'
FROM a_customer c
WHERE s.customer_id=c.customer_id AND name='Thermo Power')
```

It seems no matter where im putting parenthesis it will give me an error saying im missing one here or missing one there.

Comment: It's a problem for school, I realize that using joins would make this extremely simple, my prof loves making problems that have zero real world applications.

Comment: So we're helping you do your homework? Okay, I appreciate the honesty.   Format (indent) you SQL in some reasonable manner and the issue will probably reveal its. I'll put down an answer just to start you off with something.

Comment: Make me think of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147114/237813).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try...

```
select  product_name
from    a_product p
where   exists ( select 'X'
                 from   a_item i
                 where  i.Product_id = p.product_id )
        and exists ( select item_id
                     from   a_item i
                     where  exists ( select 'X'
                                     from   a_sales_order s
                                     where  s.order_id = i.order_id ) )
        and exists ( select order_id
                     from   a_sales_order s
                     where  exists ( select 'X'
                                     from   a_customer c
                                     where  s.customer_id = c.customer_id
                                            and name = 'Thermo Power' ) )
```

Comment: Yep thanks, I knew I wasn't using my parenthesis correctly, after looking at this it makes sense why.

Answer (score 0):

I formatted your SQL in SMSS and it starts to look clear where stuff might be off.

```
SELECT product_name
  FROM a_product p
 WHERE EXISTS ((SELECT 'X'
                  FROM a_item I
                 WHERE i.Product_id=p.product_id)
   AND EXISTS (SELECT item_id
                 FROM a_item I
                WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'X'
                                FROM a_sales_order s
                               WHERE s.order_id=i.order_id)
                  AND EXISTS (SELECT order_id
                                FROM a_sales_order s
                               WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'X'
                                               FROM a_customer c
                                              WHERE s.customer_id=c.customer_id 
                                                AND name='Thermo Power')
```